# Why does $\int_{e}^{+\infty} \frac{(\ln x)^{-100}}{x} d x = 1/99$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, improper-integrals

To find the improper integral $\int_{e}^{+\infty} \frac{(\ln x)^{-100}}{x} d x$ after substitution we get $\int_{1}^{\infty}t^{-100}dt$ and thus

$\int_{e}^{+\infty} \frac{(\ln x)^{-100}}{x} d x=-\left.\frac{1}{99} \lim _{y \rightarrow+\infty} t^{-99}\right|_{1} ^{y}=-\frac{1}{99} \frac{1}{1^{99}}-(-\frac{1}{99}\cdot \lim_{y \to \infty}\frac{1}{y^{99}})=-\frac{1}{99} + \frac{1}{99}\cdot 0=-\frac{1}{99}$.

However the official solution is $1/99$. So are they wrong or is there an error in my reasoning?

Intuitively the official solution makes sense, since we are integrating a function that is strictly positive on the interval. But algebraically I can't make any sense of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a simple sign error.  We have $$\int_{t=1}^\infty t^{-100} \, dt = \left[-\frac{1}{99} t^{-99} \right]_{t=1}^\infty = \frac{1}{99} \left( 1^{-99} - \lim_{t \to \infty} t^{-99} \right) = \frac{1}{99} (1 - 0) = \frac{1}{99}.$$  Note that in the third expression, we have cancelled the negative sign in front of $-1/99$ by reversing the order of evaluation, with $t = 1$ first and $t \to \infty$ second.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_{e}^{\infty} \frac{(\ln x)^{-100}}{x} dx$$
Let $x=e^t$
$$I=\int_{1}^{\infty} t^{-100} dt= \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{t^{-99}}{-99}|_{1}^{\infty}=\frac{1}{99}.$$